# Load server database to webpage

Tags: javascript, mysql, html

currently I have my html5 webpage in a server I have. I have tested the connection and all works find. Now, I want to make a database that is stored in the server, let's say I have: (I'm learning web development )

```
dir/
   index.html
   my_db.sql
```

So the client will ask the server to make a query, delete data or insert data.
I'd like to use javascript for this. Dont know if it is possible. I have search but I **only** found information on how to make a local database in the client, have been ours looking for this without any result. Thanks

Comment: you need a web server for that... if it's JS that you want to use take a look at node.js

Comment: You need to (well, should) run a database server. Your host more than likely offers MySQL. Then you need to write the relevant server-side code to interact with the database; you cannot write to the database directly from client-side javascript. There is plenty (and I do mean plenty) of tutorials on the internet that explain how to interact with a database. Just Google your server side language + "database tutorial" and you'll get some results. For example: [php database tutorial](https://www.google.com.au/#q=php+database+tutorial)

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  There are many ways, steps and choices in going about creating a database driven site...js, ajax, json, php+mysql, etc...

Comment: A local database in the client is only accessible on that client.  It uses local storage but that's not the same as a server side database.